# Prevent Observer to be called twice

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have an observer that fires on catalog_controller_product_view event. It works fine, but when I add product to cart Magento produces another event and then redirects back to product view and here my observer is called once again.

I want to prevent this behavior. I tried to log whole `$observer` Object on first product view and after redirect from the cart, but they are absolutely the same.
Any idea, how to prevent Observer to be called twice on this event?

P.S. I'm using Magento 1.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how good my workaround is, but it works.

```
$coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
if ($event_name == 'catalog_controller_product_view' && $coreSession->getData("test") == 1){
        $coreSession->setData("test", 0);
        return;
    }
// view
if ($event_name == 'catalog_controller_product_view'){
        $coreSession->setData("test", 0);
        // Do stuff
    }
// add_to_cart 
elseif ($event_name == 'checkout_cart_add_product_complete'){
        $coreSession->setData("test", 1);
        // Do stuff
    }
```